# How to run a JavaScript function after x seconds

Tags: javascript

I am trying a JavaScript function after 10 second of body load. But it is showing immediatly after body load. I am not expert in JavaScript, so I am not able to find where is the problem. my code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=setInterval(div_show(), 10);
</script>
```

Comment: onload should have a function that can be executed, try: `window.onload=function(){ setInterval(div_show(), 10); };`

Comment: 1) use setTimeout, 2) use a function

Comment: @LearningNeverStops Your code will not work unless you remove the ()

Comment: @mplungjan haa :) correct, my mistake :| it has to be without `()` --- `window.onload=function(){ setInterval(div_show, 10); };`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        //time is set in milliseconds
        setTimeout(div_show, 10000)
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to:

1. Assign a function to `onload`. `setInterval` returns an interval id, not a function
2. Pass a function to `setInterval`, `div_show()` will call the `div_show` function and pass its return value
3. Multiple your number of seconds by 1000. `setInterval`'s second argument is accepts a number of milliseconds not seconds.

Such:

```
onload = function () {
    setInterval(div_show, 10 * 1000);
}
```

Finally, if you want to run the function 10 seconds after the document loads, rather than **every** 10 seconds starting from when the document loads, use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it inside a function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    setInterval(div_show, 10);
}
</script>
```

Also, if you're sure if you want to execute this function only `once` when the body loads, you might as well want to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. Like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(div_show, 10);
}
</script>
```

If you want 10 it to execute after 10 seconds, you need to set the timer parameter to `number of seconds * 1000`
In your case, `10*1000`

Either

```
setTimeout(div_show, 10*1000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(div_show, 10000);
```

Answer (score 3):

This code will work. Just set your time in milliseconds and write your JS code on loadAfterTime function:

```
<script>
 window.onload = function(){

        setTimeout(loadAfterTime, 1000)
};


function loadAfterTime() { 
// code you need to execute goes here. 
}
</script>
```